# How can i use eclipse editor for php?

Tags: php, eclipse, editor

im using eclipse for python but i dont know for php..

how can i do this?

You can suggest **eclipse**?

EDIT : http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation

[Sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeclipse/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the php 'plugin' - checkout pdt.

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeclipse/

Comment: sorry. which one? i cant finding..

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeclipse/

Comment: how can i import to the eclipse?

Comment: @MalcolmX: Please contact your helpdesk how you can install software on your computer.

Comment: @Eddie i downloaded this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpeclipse/

but i cant import to eclipse. How can i import to eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Eclipse PHP or PDT. Those seem to be the main ones. But [there are others](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php%20eclipse&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this one: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/